# Trying to get ids from input and checkbox but keep getting undefined angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the ids from a input box and a checkbox but I keep getting undefined. The only value that is shown in the payload is that of the checkbox.

html

```
<li class="ui-state-default" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    <label>
        <span ng-click="toggleChecked(todo.taskId, todo.done)">
            <input type="hidden" name="taskId" ng-model="todo.taskId" value="todo.taskId" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="done[]" ng-model="todo.done" value="todo.done"  ng-checked="todo.done" />
        </span>
        <span ng-class="{'done':todo.done}" ng-cloak>
            <input type="text" ng-model="todo.title" class="todoList" />
            <span class="label label-success finished">Done</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</li>
```

angularjs

```
$scope.toggleChecked = function(taskId, done) {

    $scope.done = !$scope.done;

    $scope.todo = {
      taskId: $scope.taskId,
      done: $scope.done
    };


    $http.post('/dashboard/checked', $scope.todo).success(function() {
      alert($scope.todo);
    });
};
```

Request Payload

[image]

My objective is to be able to get the "taskId" **and** "done" value to be passed to angular and angular send the values to laravel's controller which updates the checkbox value that is in the database based on the taskId. But as seen in the pic above I am only able to get the "done" value.

Comment: can you provide plunker??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working on two clicks which is resetting your value back to false, so change your code to this:

```
<li class="ui-state-default" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="done" ng-model="todo.done" ng-change="toggleChecked(todo)" />
        <span ng-class="{'done':todo.done}" ng-cloak>
            <input type="text" ng-model="todo.title" class="todoList" />
            <span class="label label-success finished">Done</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</li>
```

And your controller code:

```
$scope.toggleChecked = function(todo) {
    $http.post('/dashboard/checked', todo).success(function() {
      alert(todo);
    });
};
```

You can directly use `ng-change` to watch on check/uncheck items. Also if you use `ng-model` you don't need to set the values manually.

Cheers!